# move class function realization from .h to .cpp procedure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

ATL project "Class>Add>Implement Interface" procedure has generated a lot of class functions from IDL to header file. As I understood it would be more clever to have function realization in cpp file. Is it possible to move realization to cpp file somehow automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that many ATL classes are template classes, and the source code for templates needs to be available at each point where those classes are used (with the usual exceptions where a declaation might suffice...)

So moving the code into a separate .cpp file wouldn't work.